# Motherboard beeps fine but unable to boot (not showing CPU speed)

Tags: boot

I am unable to boot into my desktop all of a sudden.

What happens is that it beeps fine, but at the boot point where its supposed to always flash the clock speed, its stuck right before there.

What could a reason for this?

Comment: Obvious question, but have you double checked that all memory modules, expansion cards, cables etc. are well seated in their sockets?

Comment: I know it sounds pretty obvious, but I haven't heard of a CPU failing for no reasons. What happened was I was in desktop, then everything froze, rebooted and now its stuck as it is.

Comment: If it wasn't for the beep I'd say it sounds like the motherboard's dead. My machine did exactly the same - it froze and then wouldn't reboot, except there was no beep.

Comment: model numbers would be useful!

Comment: A beep just means the POST is successful. Are you able to get into the BIOS? Is anything getting printed on the screen at all?

Answer (score 0):

The POST beep is just a single beep? You might want to check motherboard or OEM documentation; it might be a diagnostic beep indicating things are *not* fine.

I had some similar issues one time where the CPU's heat-sink was not properly in contact with the CPU. It might be worth it to remove, clean, reapply thermal conductive paste, and reseat heat-sink carefully.